# Could not find method classpath() for arguments [com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha3]

Tags: android, android-studio

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.3-2'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha3'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}
// NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
// in the individual module build.gradle files

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I am using android studio 3.0 canary 6, there is a problem in build.gradle version. It creates an error while pursuing gardle build.

Answer (score 0):

use `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha6'` and `Sync`
`OR` try with 
`clean` or `rebuild` after above change 
hope its work for you